# Не работает FSM в телеграм боте

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Хочу реализовать систему промо-кодов. Написал код, но при повторном использовании промо-кода пользователю снова зачисляется валюта, хотя такого не должно быть, ведь при использовании промо-код пользователю выставляется значение 1, в хэндлере идёт проверка, если в базе данных стоит 1, то промо-код нельзя использовать.

Также при нажатии на кейборд кнопку состояние не останавливается.
Помогите пожалуйста выявить проблему. Вот сам код:

```
elif message.text == '️Промокод️':
    await PromoCode.code.set()
    await message.answer("<b>Введите ваш промокод</b> ✅",
                         parse_mode='HTML',
                         reply_markup=back())
```

Вот хэндлер обработки FSM:

```
@dp.message_handler(state=PromoCode.code)
async def FSM_Code(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    bool1 = await check_bool(message.from_user.id)
    if message.text != 'GOLDAPLUS':
        await message.answer(f"❌ Промо-кода <b>'{message.text}'</b> не существует",
                             parse_mode='HTML')
    if message.text == 'GOLDAPLUS':
        if bool1 == 1:
            await message.answer("❌ Промо-код можно использовать только один раз")
            return
        await message.answer("Отлично,<b> на ваш баланс зачислено 5 голды</b>",
                             parse_mode='HTML')
        await plus_balance(message.from_user.id, 5)
        await plus_check_promo(message.from_user.id, 1)
    elif message.text == 'Вернуться назад':
        await state.finish()
        await message.answer(" <b>Главное Меню</b>",
                             parse_mode='HTML',
                             reply_markup=kb_start())
```

Comment: сделай проверку на `кнопки назад` первой, она у тебя никогда не прокает

Answer (score 0):

Я покажу так как я сделал обработчик промокодов через машину состояний, правда через инлайн кнопку, но здесь ничего сложного.

Кратко расскажу о его алгоритме действий:

При нажатии на кнопку `"Промокод"`, пользователь входит в машину состояний, где сразу проверяется есть ли он в базе и если нет то его туда вносят сразу со всеми промокодами, но в значении `c_promo_code`(скор. от `check_promo_code`) будет находиться значение `"0"`. После чего ему приходит сообщение:

> "Введите промокод"

Юзер вводит какой-либо текст, он проверяется на наличие данного промокода и посылает ответ в зависимости от введенного текста. Если данный промокод существует, то ему начисляется бонус и в базе данных обновляется значение `c_promo_code` на `"1"` и при попытке ввести этот промокод еще раз, будет проверяться значение в бд и оно будет равно `"1"` на что пользователь получит ответ:

> "Промокод можно использовать только один раз"

Напоминаю! Я еще студент и это мой первый бот, код явно не оптимальный, но рабочий. Желательно разделить код по разным питоновским файлам(например: все `sql-запросы` в файлик `db.py` и тд.), но я для общей картины написал всё более-менее вместе

```
if call.data == 'promo_bon_cab':
    await states.promo_code.type_promo.set()
    await bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, '✍ Введите промокод:', reply_markup=kb.markup_cancel_promo)

    @dp.message_handler(state=states.promo_code.type_promo)
    async def promo_text(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
        try:
            if not BotDB.promo_exists(message.from_user.id):
                cur.execute("INSERT INTO `promo_codes` (`user_id`, `promo_code`) VALUES (?, ?)", (message.from_user.id, 'free_10_coin',))
                cur.execute("INSERT INTO `promo_codes` (`user_id`, `promo_code`) VALUES (?, ?)", (message.from_user.id, 'free_5_coin',))
                base.commit()
            async with state.proxy() as data:
                data['type_promo'] = message.text
            if data['type_promo'] == 'free_10_coin':
                for value_check_promo in cur.execute(f"SELECT c_promo_code FROM promo_codes WHERE user_id = {message.from_user.id} AND promo_code = '{data['type_promo']}'"):
                    if value_check_promo[0] != 1:
                        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '✅ Вы активировали промокод - "free_10_coin"', reply_markup=kb.markup_start)
                        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, ' Вам начислено 10 coins')
                        cur.execute(f"UPDATE promo_codes SET `c_promo_code` = 1 WHERE user_id = {message.from_user.id} AND promo_code = '{data['type_promo']}'")
                        cur.execute(f"UPDATE users SET bal_trx = bal_trx + 10 WHERE user_id = {message.from_user.id}")
                        base.commit()
                        await state.finish()
                    else:
                        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '⛔ Промокод можно использовать только один раз ❗', reply_markup=kb.markup_start)
                        await state.finish()
            elif data['type_promo'] == 'free_5_coin':
                for value_check_promo in cur.execute(f"SELECT c_promo_code FROM promo_codes WHERE user_id = {message.from_user.id} AND promo_code = '{data['type_promo']}'"):
                    if value_check_promo[0] != 1:
                        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '✅ Вы активировали промокод - "free_5_coin"', reply_markup=kb.markup_start)
                        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, ' Вам начислено 5 coins')
                        cur.execute(f"UPDATE promo_codes SET `c_promo_code` = 1 WHERE user_id = {message.from_user.id} AND promo_code = '{data['type_promo']}'")
                        cur.execute(f"UPDATE users SET bal_trx = bal_trx + 5 WHERE user_id = {message.from_user.id}")
                        base.commit()
                        await state.finish()
                    else:
                        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '⛔ Промокод можно использовать только один раз ❗', reply_markup=kb.markup_start)
                        await state.finish()
            else:
                 await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'❌ Промокода " <u><b>{message.text}</b></u> " не существует, или время его действия истекло ❗\n\nВы можете выйти из ввода промокода: /cancel_promo_code', parse_mode='html', reply_markup=kb.markup_cancel_promo)
        except:
            await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'❌ Промокод введён не коректно ❗', parse_mode='html', reply_markup=kb.markup_start)
            await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'❌ Вы вернулись в главное меню ‼', parse_mode='html')
            await state.finish()

await call.answer()
```

Листинг файла db.py

```
class BotDB:
    global base, cur
    base = sqlite3.connect('bot_db.sqlite3')
    cur = base.cursor()

        """Проверяем, есть ли юзер в базе"""
    def promo_exists(user_id):
        result = cur.execute("SELECT `id` FROM `promo_codes` WHERE `user_id` = ?", (user_id,))
        return bool(len(result.fetchall()))
```